# How to create a Unit Test to access Views in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Im new to create a Unit Tests for Service class. Im facing an issue in accessing views in my context.
I have a two contexts one for writing and one for reading.Below are the sample for the context file for reading.

```
public class readContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IOptions<DatabaseConfig> _dbConfiguration;

    public readContext(IOptions<DatabaseConfig> dbConfiguration)
    {
        _dbConfiguration = dbConfiguration;
    }
 
    public DbSet<AppVM> AppVMs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AppVMMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_dbConfiguration.Value);
    }
}
```

Write Context:

```
public class writeContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IOptions<DatabaseConfig> _dbConfiguration;

    public static readonly LoggerFactory _myLoggerFactory =
    new LoggerFactory(new[] {
        new DebugLoggerProvider()
    });

    public writeContext(IOptions<DatabaseConfig> dbConfiguration)
    {
        _dbConfiguration = dbConfiguration;
    }

    public writeContext(DbContextOptions _dbConfiguration) : base(_dbConfiguration)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sample1> Sample1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sample2> Sample2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sample3> Sample3 { get; set; }       

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new sample1Map());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new sample2Map());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new sample3Map());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_myLoggerFactory);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveEntitiesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await base.SaveChangesAsync();

        return true;
    }
}
```

In Unit Test - Setup method, I'm trying to create a Inmemory DB to access the above context.

```
var writeBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<writeContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Sample").EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        _writeContext = new writeContext(writeBuilder.Options);    
      
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<readContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Sample")                                        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        var context = new readContext(builder.Options);
```

But after this, I'm completely blank and don't know how to access the views. So is that possible to mock DB and access views.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Based on your description, you have two dbcontexts, one is used to write and the other is used to view. Then, what is used for AppContext, view or write? what issues did you meet when you access views? If possible, Please provide another dbcontext class.

Comment: I have updated my question. I would like to run a simple get method test and want to know is there a possibility to access views using the above context.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework Core, you could create custom queries using your DbContext for accessing views in your unit tests. You can try the following code to see if it helps you. If there are any questions, please let me know.

In your DbContext class, create a custom query method that returns data from the view.

```
public IQueryable<AppVM> GetAppVMs()
{
    return AppVMs;
}
```

In your unit test methods, use the custom query method to access data from the view.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_GetAppVMs()
{
    // Arrange: Create an instance of the DbContext
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<readContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Sample")
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    var context = new readContext(builder.Options);

    // Act: Call the custom query method to get data from the view
    var appVMs = context.GetAppVMs().ToList();

    // Assert: Perform your assertions on the retrieved data
    Assert.AreEqual(10, appVMs.Count);
}
```

This example assumes that AppVM is the class or model that represents the structure of your view. Replace it with the appropriate class name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try it and let you know if I face any issues.